# Running another program using Python

Tags: python, external-process

I have a program that processes files and returns another file as output. When I am running it in cmd I first set the path: "cd c:\program" and then set it to process the file located in the program folder: "program test.txt". I would like a python program to do it for me using the subprocess module, but I can't get it to work.

I have read the related posts and I know it should be a no-brainer, but as a novice I haven't been able to figure it out. Help greatly appriciated.

Here is one example of the code I tried. It runs, but doesn't produce any results.

```
import subprocess

textfile = 'c:\program\test.txt'
programPath = r'C:\program\program.exe'
subprocess.Popen([programPath, textfile])
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what went wrong: program + error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "It runs, but doesn't produce any results"? How can you tell it's running? How do you expect results to be produced?

Comment: What I meant is that it does not produce an error. Also it does not produce the desired results.

Comment: Maybe `Popen` is not what you want. You might want to try [`subprocess.check_call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to prepend `r` to `textfile`'s literal:

```
textfile = r'c:\program\test.txt'
```

(`\t` is a tab character. Next time, please include any error messages in the post as well.)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there wouldn't typically be any error message from this issue. But prepending `r` is right

Comment: @DavidRobinson: `program.exe` would (hopefully) give an error message.

Comment: Thank you. Embarrasingly it solves the problem. (the mistake didn't produce an error though - thats why I thought I was more conceptually wrong here.